# Cannot bootup windows 7 after upgrading to ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, dual-boot, windows-7

I have tried

```
boot-repair
grub-update
bootrec commands
booting into safe mode with command prompt gets stuck with classpnp.sys file
changing sata options in bios 
etc
```

but windows keep throwing the STOP error /blue screen.

Heres details from boot-repair 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/5804023/

I have updated Ubuntu from 10.x to 12.x and have lost a day with no productive work

heres a screenshot of the blue screen
[image]

Comment: As crazy as this might sound, but try removing the CMOS battery, reboot, then re-install it, and reboot the machine again.

Comment: any reason how it can help?

Comment: The problem could as simple as a failing CMOS battery.  Also make sure that all your drives, are securely connected, and cables a re OK.

Answer (score 0):

Is "recovery-partition" (installed by vendor) linked to your Bios resp. to your Win7 ? - (I had that too 1 year ago.) if it got deleted by Ubuntu-update, then you might rescue your Win7 and Ubuntu datas with a backup by live-system like knoppix on to an usb-harddisk.

> dd if=/dev/sda of=/media/name-of-usb-disk

Then make complete new hard-disk (partition-table) with seperated partitions for each Win7 and Ubuntu (with gparted). Before new installation of Ubuntu, then install Win7 on ntfs-partition (first boot-partition). When Win7-installation is complete, then install Ubuntu on e.g. ext4-partition. I think this is easiest solution for this. Looks humblesome but works (simply goes the whole hog).

Comment: i am new to ubuntu so some steps might help, i kind of understand your flow but not exactly get the steps